# Получить расстояние между центром и краем объекта

Tags: unity3d

**Мне нужно получить расстояние между краем и центром объекта.**

Рисунок который показывает чего я хочу:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы принципиально не отмечаете ответы, как верные, во всех своих вопросах? :)

Comment: Но они и вправду верные!

Comment: Ну так и отметьте их, как верные, проведите ревизию своих вопросов и закройте отвеченные вопросы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Размер объекта напрямую зависит от 2х вещей - от самой mesh'ы и его transform'а. Чтобы получить этот размер, нужно найти его AABB (англ. Axis Aligned Bounding Box).

В конкретно Unity его можно получить двумя способами:

- `Mesh.bounds`
- `Renderer.bounds`

Первый возвращает AABB без трансформации матрицей transform'а, что нам совершенно не подходит, а вот второй возвращает уже измененный AABB.

---

```
// AABB
Bounds bounds = GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds;
// Размеры по всем трем осям
Vector3 extents = bounds.extents;

Debug.Log(extents);
```

`extents` - это и есть искомое расстояние от центра объекта до его краев по всем осям, если брать конкретно этот вопрос, то расстояние от центра до правого/левого края будет `extents.x`.

Comment: Следует принимать во внимание что центр `Renderer.bounds` может не совпадать с `Transform.position`.

Comment: @KingPeas, кстати говоря, ни разу не сталкивался с такой ситуацией, когда центр меши расположен не в "центре". Если вам есть, что добавить по данному вопросу - буду только рад.

Comment: если вы грузите объект из макса, то в зависимости от того где задан центр в модели в 3D редакторе он может не совпадать с центром `Bounds`. Ну а если модель неправильной формы, так это вообще сплошь и рядом. В стандартных мешах, типа кубика или капсулы там конечно да, все совпадает, а вот загруженные совсем не факт.

Comment: @KingPeas, ну тут спорно, вопрос все же был связан с боксом для проверки, видит ли объект камера. И бокс от рендерера учитывает весь "размер" модели, насколько я знаю.

Comment: нигде  в вопросе не увидел что речь идет про бокс)

Comment: @KingPeas, под боксом я подразумевал `Bounds`, жаргон, извиняюсь :)