# Немного доработать готовый кусок кода

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть код(не мой) для того чтобы объект не выходил за границы камеры, но когда объект доходит до границы камеры то объект на половину от своего размера выходит за камеру как сделать чтобы объект не выходил даже на половину, а сразу "тютилька в тютельку" врезался в края.

Код:

```
Vector3 cameraToObject = transform.position - Camera.main.transform.position;
// отрицание потому что игровые объекты в данном случае находятся ниже камеры по оси y
float distance = -Vector3.Project(cameraToObject, Camera.main.transform.forward).y - GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.extents.y;

// вершины "среза" пирамиды видимости камеры на необходимом расстоянии от камеры
Vector3 leftBot  = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, distance));
Vector3 rightTop = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(1, 1, distance));

// границы в плоскости XZ, т.к. камера стоит выше остальных объектов
float x_left  = leftBot.x;
float x_right = rightTop.x;
float z_top   = rightTop.z;
float z_bot   = leftBot.z;

// ограничиваем объект в плоскости XZ
Vector3 clampedPos = transform.position;
clampedPos.x = Mathf.Clamp(clampedPos.x, x_left, x_right);
clampedPos.z = Mathf.Clamp(clampedPos.z, z_bot, z_top);
transform.position = clampedPos;
```

Как это работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отредактировал изначальный код, чтобы добиться поведения, указанного в скриншоте

Comment: Теперь наблюдаем такую картину: https://imgur.com/a/nbLAF12

Comment: Вы понимаете, что перспективная камера не предназначена для таких манипуляций? Геометрически вы не выходите  за рамки, но с точки зрения камеры такое получить... это вам к ортогональной камере.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Надо применить знания из уже заданного вами вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/914531/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0/914544#914544), получить размеры объекта:

```
// Размеры по всем трем осям
Vector3 extents;

private void Awake() {
    extents = GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.extents;
}
```

И сместить крайние значения положения объекта по осям на значения размера объекта:

```
float x_left  = leftBot.x + extents.x;
float x_right = rightTop.x - extents.x;
float z_top   = rightTop.z - extents.z;
float z_bot   = leftBot.z + extents.z;
```

---

Ну и закономерный результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё равно кусочек уходит по оси x а вот по z всё норм: https://imgur.com/a/SwwfgGw

Comment: А как вы, интересно, хотите на перспективной камере получить другой результат? Сам объект за границы не выходит, это именно камера это недорисовывает. Хотите вот прямо то, что вы показали на скриншоте - вам нужно поменять высоту для среза плоскости пирамиды видимости.

Comment: Это хороший и правильный ответ. И коментарии толковые. Не забывай отмечать ответ галочкой, который помог. А то не дело. Человек на тебя время свое тратил, а ты "спасибо" так и не показал.